# Extend argparse to write set names in the help text for optional argument choices and define those sets once at the end

Tags: python, argparse

## Example of the problem

If I have a list of valid option strings which is shared between several arguments, the list is written in multiple places in the help string. Making it harder to read:

```
def main():
    elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i',
        nargs='*',
        choices=elements,
        default=elements,
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-e',
        nargs='*',
        choices=elements,
        default=[],
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names to '
        'exclude from processing')

    parser.parse_args()
```

When running the above function with the command line argument `--help` it shows:

```
usage: arguments.py [-h] [-i [{a,b,c,d,e,f} [{a,b,c,d,e,f} ...]]]
                    [-e [{a,b,c,d,e,f} [{a,b,c,d,e,f} ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i [{a,b,c,d,e,f} [{a,b,c,d,e,f} ...]]
                        Space separated list of case sensitive element names.
  -e [{a,b,c,d,e,f} [{a,b,c,d,e,f} ...]]
                        Space separated list of case sensitive element names
                        to exclude from processing
```

---

## What would be nice

It would be nice if one could define an option list name, and in the help output write the option list name in multiple places and define it last of all. In theory it would work like this:

```
def main_optionlist():
    elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

    # Two instances of OptionList are equal if and only if they
    # have the same name (ALFA in this case)

    ol = OptionList('ALFA', elements)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i',
        nargs='*',
        choices=ol,
        default=ol,
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-e',
        nargs='*',
        choices=ol,
        default=[],
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names to '
        'exclude from processing')

    parser.parse_args()
```

And when running the above function with the command line argument `--help` it would show something similar to:

```
usage: arguments.py [-h] [-i [ALFA [ALFA ...]]]
                    [-e [ALFA [ALFA ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i [ALFA [ALFA ...]]
                        Space separated list of case sensitive element names.
  -e [ALFA [ALFA ...]]
                        Space separated list of case sensitive element names
                        to exclude from processing
sets in optional arguments:
  ALFA                  {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

---

## Question

I need to:

- Replace the {'l', 'i', 's', 't', 's'} shown with the option name, in the optional arguments.
- At the end of the help text show a section explaining which elements each option name consists of.

So I ask:

1. Is this possible using argparse?
2. Which classes would I have to inherit from and which methods would I need to override?

I have tried looking at the source for argparse, but as this modification feels pretty advanced I don´t know how to get going.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you given [`plac`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac) a look to see if it meets your requirements?

Comment: No, we try to use the standard modules as far as possible. But I´ll be sure to check it out during my spare time, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A completely generic solution as per request by the now deleted bounty-donator and in contrast to the other answers:

```
import argparse
from operator import itemgetter

class OptionListGroup(object):
  class GroupAction(object):
    def __init__(self, left, right):
      self.help = right
      self.option_strings = [left]
      self.nargs = 0

  def __init__(self, lists):
    self.description = None
    self.title = "referenced sets"
    self._group_actions = [self.GroupAction(name, self.format_list(lst))
                           for name, lst in sorted(lists)]

  def format_list(self, lst):
    return '{%s}' % ', '.join(map(str, lst))

class MyArgParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._option_lists = {}
    super(MyArgParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def parse_args(self, *args, **kw):
    self._action_groups.append(OptionListGroup(self._option_lists.values()))
    return super(MyArgParser, self).parse_args(*args, **kw)

  def add_option_list(self, name, lst):
    if name in map(itemgetter(0), self._option_lists.values()):
      raise ValueError, "Name already existing"
    self._option_lists[id(lst)] = (name, lst)

  def add_argument(self, *args, **kw):
    name_list = self._option_lists.get(id(kw.get('choices')))
    if name_list:
      kw['metavar'] = name_list[0]
    return super(MyArgParser, self).add_argument(*args, **kw)
```

Example usage:

```
alfa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
num = [1, 2, 3]

parser = MyArgParser()

parser.add_option_list('ALFA', alfa)
parser.add_option_list('NUM', num)

parser.add_argument(
  '-a',
  nargs='*',
  choices=alfa,
  default=alfa,
  help='Characters (defaults to include all)')

parser.add_argument(
  '-e',
  nargs='*',
  choices=num,
  default=[],
  help='Digits (defaults to exclude all)')

parser.parse_args()
```

Help output:

```
usage: argparse-optionlist.py [-h] [-a [ALFA [ALFA ...]]]
                              [-e [NUM [NUM ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a [ALFA [ALFA ...]]  Characters (defaults to include all)
  -e [NUM [NUM ...]]    Digits (defaults to exclude all)

referenced sets:
  ALFA                  {a, b, c, d, e, f}
  NUM                   {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 19):

My answer doesn't attempt to extend argparse at all, but rather uses the available options of argparse as it is... Does this solve your situation?

```
import argparse
import textwrap

def main():
    elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        epilog = textwrap.dedent('''\
            sets in optional arguments: 
                ALFA\t\t{a,b,c,d,e,f}"
            '''))

    parser.add_argument(
        '-i',
        nargs='*',
        choices=elements,
        default=elements,
        metavar="ALFA",
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-e',
        nargs='*',
        choices=elements,
        default=[],
        metavar="ALFA",
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names to '
        'exclude from processing')

    parser.parse_args()
```

#### Output

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-i [ALFA [ALFA ...]]] [-e [ALFA [ALFA ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i [ALFA [ALFA ...]]  Space separated list of case sensitive element names.
  -e [ALFA [ALFA ...]]  Space separated list of case sensitive element names
                        to exclude from processing

sets in optional arguments: 
    ALFA                {a,b,c,d,e,f}"
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can freely name the metavar whatever you want for each flag, and you can manually format the epilog to reflect any format description as well. No subclassing needed.

Comment: I like this approach better for not having to subclass or do anything more complex than just using the argparse options

Comment: This is elegant. I learned five things about argparse from this example. This is going to help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you want. . ., How about something similar to the following:

```
import argparse

elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

class myparser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def add_argument(self,*args,**kwargs):
        choice=kwargs.get('choices',None)
        if(choice is elements):
            kwargs['metavar']='ALFA'

        return argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument(self,*args,**kwargs)

def main():

    epilog="""sets in optional arguments:
  ALFA                  %s"""%(str(elements).replace('[','{').replace(']','}'))

    parser = myparser(epilog=epilog,formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter) 
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i',
        nargs='*',
        choices=elements,
        default=elements,
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-e',
        nargs='*',
        choices=elements,
        default=[],
        help='Space separated list of case sensitive element names to '
        'exclude from processing')

    parser.parse_args()


main()
```

Optionally, you could just use the `metavar` keyword directly.  The formatter change is to make the epilog appear the way you want it.  Generally i would advise against using it.

**EDIT**

Depending on your python version, you may have `RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` available which I would advise using for this problem.